# NEON optimized libraries on Android

Tags: android, libraries, neon

ARM website states that there are certain NEON optimized libraries and [show examples](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s04s04.html) of using them. Trying to incorporate them into an Android project that takes advantage of NEON architecture isn't possible. The header files and libraries aren't there.

Is there a way to manually import those into an Android project? I am particularly interested in OpenMAX.

Comment: I am wandering is there any 2d or 3d vector library that can use neon to speed up, there is math neon, but it dont have functions that i use, http://code.google.com/p/math-neon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly what you need and you can't find it, its probably best just to go ahead and write your own assembly it may even out perform the library unless of course the library is written in pure assembly then that might be hard but any library written in C and assembly inline has room for some extra performance (although not an extreme amount).

Comment: The OpenMAX libraries are written and compiled for optimal performance on ARM. In any case, your point is correct in that Assembly looks best in terms of optimization, but only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Phonon is definitely right, if you go down the assembly path be prepared to be learning and trying a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Writing NEON codes is actually much easier than ARM codes.

Optimizing is a different story though......

It's just like the Holy Grail. Fully optimized NEON codes usually run 10~20 times faster than their counterparts written in C.

It's an extremely taxing job though.